# How to create header xamarin listview?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

```
lst.Adapter=new CustomAdapter(Android.App.Application.Context,items);

public class CustomAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
        private  const int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
        private const int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;

        string[] mnData;
        //private TreeSet sectionHeader;

        LayoutInflater mInflater;
        TreeSet sectionHeader;

        public CustomAdapter(Context context, string[] Data) {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.FromContext (context);

            mnData=Data;
        }

        public override int GetItemViewType (int position)
        {
            return sectionHeader.Contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;
        }

        public override int ViewTypeCount
        {
            get { return 2; }
        }

        public override int Count {
            get {return mnData.Length;}
        }


        public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position) {
            return mnData[position];
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        } 

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            //var data = mData [position];
            var item=mnData[position];
            int row = GetItemViewType (position);
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder ();
                switch (row) {
                case TYPE_ITEM:
                    convertView = mInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.textGenreItems, parent, false);
                    holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.FindViewById (Resource.Id.textTitleGenre);
                    break;
                case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                    convertView = mInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.textGenreHeaderItems, parent, false);
                    holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.FindViewById (Resource.Id.textHeaderGenre);
                    break;
                }

                convertView.Tag = holder;
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.Tag as ViewHolder;
            }



            return convertView;
        }
    }

    public  class ViewHolder:Java.Lang.Object {
        public TextView textView{ get; set; }
        //public TextView textViewSeparator{ get; set; }
```

- I want to create a listview as following picture. How to do that?

Here's how I do it, the keys are getItemViewType and getViewTypeCount in the Adapter class. getViewTypeCount returns how many types of items we have in the list, in this case we have a header item and an event item, so two.  getItemViewType should return what type of View we have at the input position.

Android will then take care of passing you the right type of View in convertView automatically.

[image]

Comment: What you are looking for is called a sectioned listview adapter. You need to override ViewTypeCount and GetItemViewType method. With that you need to check the view type in the GetView method and depending on the type inflate the layout.

Comment: int GetItemViewType return null

Comment: Please to help me.